How to Project an Entire Line onto a Vector?
I'm trying to understand how to project an entire line in 2D onto a given vector, but I'm unsure of the correct method to apply the transformation.
For example, consider the line equation:
$3x_1 + 4x_2 - 3 = 0$
and the vector $\mathbf{u} = (2, 1)$.
I want to project this line onto the vector $\mathbf{u}$. My initial thought was to project the normal vector of the line onto $\mathbf{u}$, but I realized this doesn’t seem to give me the correct result for the whole line. I'm not sure how to handle the constant term from the line equation or how the projection affects the position of the line, not just its direction.
What is the correct method for projecting a line, such as $3x_1 + 4x_2 - 3 = 0$, onto a vector $\mathbf{u}$?
If it helps I know the answer is supposed to be $x_1 - 2  x_2 = 0$ but I have no clue how they got there.
Thanks a lot!

Ususlly we project vectors onto a line that is onto its direction vectors.

What is the definition of the projection of the line onto a vector?

Maybe I misunderstood the question, the question is(and it is translated from a different language): Apply a map to the line 3x_1 + 4x_2 - 3 = 0
And one of the mappings was the projection onto a vector $\vec{u} = (2,1)$
So P(x) = $\frac{\vec{x}.\vec{u}}{\vec{u}.\vec{u}}\vec{u}$

Ah ok maybe for a parametrized line, that is for any vector in the line, but we need to assume an origin on the line.

If it helps I know the answer is supposed to be $x_1 - 2  x_2 = 0$ but I have no clue how they got there.

You should add that information editing your question. If so it seems that the result is simply the line which has $u$ as direction vector.

Since line $3x_1 + 4x_2 - 3 = 0$ has direction vector $\mathbf{v} = (4, -3)$ not orthogonal to $\mathbf{u} = (2, 1)$, since $\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v}\neq 0$, the projection is simply the line through the origin with $\mathbf{u}$ as direction vector that is indeed $x_1-2x_2=0$.

The original line doesn't pass through the origin tho, you could definitely be right and you probably are, I just don't see how this exercise makes sense then. Thanks a lot for the help!

This is not essential that the line to project pass throught the origin, any vector on the line is projected into a vector onto a line thorugh the origin. This is true for all the lines unless for the lines orthogonal which projection is a point (that is a vector).
